# Can't break a while loop. Reading undefined array size

Tags: c

I have this sequence of letters and numbers, in which the letters are always these four: s, S, m, M. The numbers can have any value. Since the size of the sequence is not given, I just can't use a *for loop*, so I decided to use a while loop, but I'm having issues on breaking the loop.

Some input examples are:

```
12 s 80 s 3 m 12 M 240 S 8 m 30 s 240 s 1440 S 8 m 18 s 60 M

5 m 120 s 30 s 360 S 6 M 5 s 42 S 36 M 8 m 66 M 3240 S 14 m
```

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

int n[100], i = 0;
char x[100];

while(x[i] != '\n')
{
 scanf(" %d %c", &n[i], &x[i]);
 printf("%d %c ", n[i], x[i]);
 i++;
}

return 0;
}
```

Any toughts on how to break the loop, and have all this values saved correctly on the array?

Comment: First decide on when you want the loop to break. For example do you want the person to type "end" or what?

Comment: `x[i] != '\n'` is testing an uninitialized variable

Comment: I want to break it when the user press <ENTER>

Comment: In that case you cannot use space in the scanf format string, as that means to skip past "whitespace" (which includes spaces and newlines).  You could use the `fgets` function to read a whole line, and then the `sscanf` function to get items out of that line

Comment: I also tested this way: `while((x[i] == 's') || (x[i] == 'S') || (x[i] == 'm') || (x[i] == 'M'))`

Comment: `sscanf` requires a diferent library?

Comment: No, it's in stdio.h

Comment: But how can I use `fgets` if I don't have my array size??

Comment: You can pick a size, and if fgets doesn't read the whole line, then make sure you handle the cutoff point correctly and call fgets again to read more.  Another way would be to use a loop of dynamic allocation to read the whole line.  You could look for examples on the internet or a book of how to do this

Comment: indentation.......................

Comment: @M.M I couldn't figure out how to use `sscanf` to solve this and went with `strtok` instead. Can you post an answer or give a sketch?

Comment: The blank for the `%c` in `"%d %c"` means that the `%c` will never see a newline because the blank cause `scanf()` to read all the white space (which includes blanks, tabs and newlines) before it reads a character that isn't white space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int n[100], i, j;
    char x[100];

    do {
        for(i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
            int ch;
            while((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n'){//check newline
                if(ch == '-' || '0' <= ch && ch <= '9'){
                    ungetc(ch, stdin);//back to stream a character
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(ch == EOF || ch == '\n')
                break;
            if(2 != scanf("%d %c", &n[i], &x[i])){
                fprintf(stderr, "invalid format.\n");
                i = 0;//End the outer do-while loop
                break;
            }
        }
        //print
        for(j = 0; j < i; ++j){
            printf("(%d, %c)", n[j], x[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } while(i != 0);//End with empty line
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DATA_MAX_LEN 100

int main(void){
    int n[DATA_MAX_LEN], i, len, loop_end;
    char x[DATA_MAX_LEN], newline[2], ch;

    while(scanf("%1[\n]", newline) != 1){//End with empty line(only newline), Need EOF check
        for(loop_end = len = i = 0; i < DATA_MAX_LEN && !loop_end; ++i){
            //format: integer character[space|newline]
            if(scanf("%d %c%c", &n[i], &x[i], &ch) != 3)
                loop_end = printf("invalid format.\n");
            else if(ch == '\n')
                loop_end = len = ++i;
            else if(ch != ' ')
                loop_end = printf("invalid format.\n");
        }
        for(i = 0; i < len; ++i){
            printf("%d %c ", n[i], x[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. But I must say it's quite advanced to me. I'm new to C language, so there are a few things I never used, such as: `getchar`, `ungetc`, `EOF`, or `fprintf`. Also, my teacher does not allow us to use _break_ statements, only in switch-case format. In conclusion I understood just a little of what you've done. Will try do develop a simpler method based on what you wrote.

Comment: @IgorBraga I added another solution.

Answer (score 0):

[`scanf` and `fscanf` have many problems](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html) so it's best to avoid them.

The general pattern for dealing with input is to create a large input buffer, and then process that into smaller chunks.

```
char line[4096];
fgets( line, sizeof(line), stdin );
```

Since `line` is reused it's ok to make it large enough to hold any reasonable input.

---

Now that you've read a line into memory, it's a string of known size to process as you like. `sscanf` (scanf on a string) doesn't have most of the problems of `scanf`, but it's also not suited to moving through a string. One approach is to split the string into tokens on whitespace with [`strtok`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm), and process them alternately as letters and numbers.

```
const char sep[] = " \t\n";
bool expect_letter = false;
for(
    char *token = strtok( line, sep );
    token != NULL;
    token = strtok( NULL, sep )
) {
    if( expect_letter ) {
        printf("Letter %s\n", token);
        expect_letter = false;
    }
    else {
        printf("Number %s\n", token);
        expect_letter = true;
    }    
}
```

---

If you want to store them in an array, it's bad practice to allocate what you hope is enough memory. You'll have to use an array that grows as needed. C does not have these built in. You can write your own, and it's a good exercise, but it's easy to get wrong. For production [use one from a library such as Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Arrays.html).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <glib.h>

int main() {
    // Read a single line of input into a buffer.
    char line[4096];
    fgets( line, sizeof(line), stdin );

    // Create arrays to hold letters and numbers, these will grow as needed.
    GArray *numbers = g_array_new( FALSE, TRUE, sizeof(int) );
    GArray *letters = g_array_new( FALSE, TRUE, sizeof(char) );

    // Split the string on whitespace into tokens.
    const char sep[] = " \t\n";
    gboolean expect_letter = FALSE;
    for(
        char *token = strtok( line, sep );
        token != NULL;
        token = strtok( NULL, sep )
    ) {
        if( expect_letter ) {
            // Need an error check to ensure that `token` is a single character.
            g_array_append_val( letters, token[0] );
            expect_letter = FALSE;
        }
        else {
            // strtol is a better choice, it has error checking
            int num = atoi(token);
            g_array_append_val( numbers, num );
            expect_letter = TRUE;
        }
    }

    // Print the numbers and letters.
    for( guint i = 0; i < letters->len; i++ ) {
        printf(
            "%d%c\n",
            g_array_index( numbers, int, i ),
            g_array_index( letters, char, i )
        );
    }
}
```

Note that GLib provides its own boolean, so I switched to that instead of stdbool to keep things consistent.

As noted in the comments, this does not include checks that the token is what you expect. It's also possible to have a number with no letter, so checking that `letters` and `numbers` are the same size would be good. Or you can make a struct to hold the letter/number pairs and have a single list of those structs.